# run a function in background even when the browser is closed

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Is there a way so that I can run a javascript function in the background even when the browser has been closed by the user. It can be done in android apps i have done it too. but don't know about javascript.

Comment: javascript runs on the browser so when the browser is closed, javascript can't run. Android apps are run on the operating system so as long as the android device is on, the apps will run

Comment: @Manu is correct. If you're looking to do something before browser is closed, you can call `onBeforeUnload` event

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers

Comment: You can not run functions (without extensions) in the background but you could save some data in the localStorage. This data is then stored for the specific domain and you can use it when the page is opened again

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you make your javascript function into [Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#background).

It works even when browser closed.

> When any installed hosted app, packaged app, or extension has
>   "background" permission, Chrome runs (invisibly) as soon as the user
>   logs into their computer—before the user launches Chrome. The
>   "background" permission also makes Chrome continue running (even after
>   its last window is closed) until the user explicitly quits Chrome.

Comment: i have a webapp. i want to send notification to user even when browser is closed.

Comment: my answer is for PC / Mac. from what I know you need a native app for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to run a client side javascript function in the background when the browser is closed - if the program is a web app.

If you want to send notifications you may be able to use service workers. However, there is limited support right now. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers